# Confirming cubic spline was done on imputed datasets (imputed by mice Package) and the estimate is the pooled based on Rubin's rule

Tags: cox-model, splines, multiple-imputation, rms, mice

I am performing restricted cubic spline (Cox proportional hazard ratio) after imputing 10 datasets using mice package.

My variables as follow:

Outcome: DM

Exposure: BMI

time to events: time

Covariates: age, sex, phy, smk2, alco

I am using the following codes:

```
library(mice)
library(Hmisc)
library (rms)
d<-datadist(DMs)
options(datadist = "d")
d$limits["Adjust to","BMI"] <- 25
```

#Multiple Imputation

```
DMs1<- mice::mice(DM,seed = 123, print = FALSE,m=10, maxit = 5)
```

#Restricted cubic spline model

```
models<-fit.mult.impute(Surv(time, DM) ~ rcs(BMI,4)+age+sex+phy+
                      smk2+alco, fitter = cph, xtrans = DM1,data = DMs,x=TRUE, Y=TRUE)
```

#applying the model in the data

```
dataplot<-Predict(models,BMI=seq(18,40,by=2),ref.zero = TRUE, fun = exp)
```

#ploting data

```
ggplot(dataplot,aes(BMI,yhat))
```

My question is how to confirm that  restricted cubic spline was done on 10 datasets and the estimate was the pooled based on Rubin's rule?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a question about how multiple imputations are handled, compare the results on the individual imputed data sets to what was reported for the pooled imputations. I don't have your data, but the `jasa` dataset from the `survival` package has some missing data in the `mscore` variable (among others) to use as an example. I got a warning related to `Date` objects when I tried to use all the columns, so omit the first 3.

```
library(mice)
library(rms) ## also loads Hmisc, survival, etc.
ddJ <- datadist(jasa[,4:14])
options(datadist="ddJ")
m1 <- mice(jasa[4:14],m=10,seed=123,print=FALSE,maxit=5)
models <- fit.mult.impute(Surv(futime,fustat)~rcs(age,3) + mscore,fitter=cph,xtrans=m1,data= jasa[,4:14],x=TRUE,y=TRUE)

# Variance Inflation Factors Due to Imputation:
# 
#    age   age' mscore 
#   1.01   1.00   1.52 
# 
# Rate of Missing Information:
# 
#    age   age' mscore 
#   0.01   0.00   0.34 
# 
# d.f. for t-distribution for Tests of Single Coefficients:
# 
#        age       age'     mscore 
#  175205.19 1356056.66      76.09 
# 
# The following fit components were averaged over the 10 model fits:
# 
#   linear.predictors means stats center 
#
```

That output on its own should start to set your mind at ease, as it states how much the results are affected by imputation.

You can ask the `mice` package to retrieve a list of all 10 imputed data sets.

```
c1 <- complete(m1,action="all")
```

As you might expect, the coefficients reported for `models` are the averages of those for the individual models.

```
indivCoefs <- NULL
for(i in 1:10) indivCoefs <- rbind(indivCoefs,coef(cph(Surv(futime,fustat)~rcs(age,3) + mscore,data=c1[[i]],x=TRUE,y=TRUE)))
indivCoefs
#                 age       age'     mscore
#  [1,] -0.0007819043 0.03417368 0.02641657
#  [2,] -0.0016521256 0.03251149 0.35839812
#  [3,] -0.0027189336 0.03357772 0.24265117
#  [4,] -0.0024670263 0.03256148 0.35220641
#  [5,] -0.0043502230 0.03500199 0.30231338
#  [6,] -0.0026773902 0.03471552 0.17250318
#  [7,] -0.0030487879 0.03435990 0.38502635
#  [8,]  0.0002067658 0.03332910 0.30456262
#  [9,]  0.0022994480 0.03166086 0.53495959
# [10,] -0.0010426317 0.03289308 0.37069055

apply(indivCoefs,MARGIN=2,FUN=mean)
#          age         age'       mscore 
# -0.001623281  0.033478483  0.304972793

coef(models)
#         age         age'       mscore 
# -0.001623281  0.033478483  0.304972793
```

The `age'` coefficient is specific to the `rcs()` function, so that function was used in all model fits. One caution: the documentation for `fit.mult.impute()` specifies that the knot positions are kept constant after they are chosen for the first imputed data set.

In contrast, the pooled variance/covariance matrix isn't the average of the 10 individual matrices.

```
indivVcov <- vcov(cph(Surv(futime,fustat)~rcs(age,3) + mscore,data=c1[[1]],x=TRUE,y=TRUE))
for(i in 2:10) indivVcov <-indivVcov+vcov(cph(Surv(futime,fustat)~rcs(age,3) + mscore,data=c1[[i]],x=TRUE,y=TRUE)))

indivVcov/10
#                  age          age'        mscore
# age     0.0005464355 -0.0004401314 -0.0002257020
# age'   -0.0004401314  0.0004999929 -0.0000294507
# mscore -0.0002257020 -0.0000294507  0.0391095587

vcov(models)
#                  age          age'        mscore
# age     0.0005503802 -0.0004417423 -0.0001322173
# age'   -0.0004417423  0.0005012843 -0.0001331701
# mscore -0.0001322173 -0.0001331701  0.0596110650
```

In particular, notice the higher pooled variance for `mscore` than the average over the 10 imputations. That because additional computations applying Rubin's rules have been used.

Some of the confusion might come from the following sentence from the `fit.mult.impute` help documentation (within the `transcan` documentation):

> `fit.mult.impute` returns a fit object that is a modification of the fit object created by fitting the completed dataset for the final imputation.

You don't get a set of `models` from it. Instead you get a single pooled model. But it's not the fit for "the completed dataset for the final imputation," which is simply used as a template. The documentation then goes on to say:

> The `var` matrix in the fit object has the imputation-corrected variance-covariance matrix.

That's what's returned by `vcov(models)`. All that `Predict()` has to work with is that single pooled model, with the averaged coefficients and the imputation-corrected coefficient covariance matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer.